# Discord Bot always replies one more message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Respons Picture

[image: 1]

Hi my Bot always replies one more message, The command works you press the button enter a reason in the text input field and then you select a platform from the drop down menu. But instead of sending the embed once, it sends it multiple times each time.

Error: Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
Or: "Interaction has already been acknowledged."

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Command = require('../../structures/CommandClass');
const { stripIndents } = require('common-tags');
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, TextInputStyle, StringSelectMenuBuilder, Events, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder } = require('discord.js');


    
module.exports = class spielersucheerweitert extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
                .setName('sendspielersuche')
                .setDescription('Sende das Spielersuche Embed')
                .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)
                .setDMPermission(false),          
        });
    }
        
      
  async run(client, interaction) {
    
    let member = await interaction.member.fetch();
    
    

      const pfmenü = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('pfmenü')
                    .setPlaceholder('Plattform auswählen')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'PS4',                           
                            value: 'ps4',
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'PS5',                           
                            value: 'ps5',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'PS4/PS5',                           
                            value: 'ps4ps5',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'PC',                        
                            value: 'pc',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Switch',                            
                            value: 'switch',
                        },
            {
                            label: 'Alle',      
                            value: 'alle',
                        },
                    ),
            );


      
      const modals = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('minput')
            .setTitle('Spielersuche ');


      const spielinput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('spielinput') 
            .setLabel("Für welches Spiel?")
      .setPlaceholder('GTA5, Fortnite, Call of Duty, Minecraft ...')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setMinLength(2)
      .setMaxLength(20)
      .setRequired(true);

      const grundinput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('grundinput')         
            .setLabel("Der Grund der Anfrage?")   
      .setPlaceholder('Beispiel: Suche Spieler für Cayo Perico Heist.') 
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
      .setMinLength(10)
      .setMaxLength(60)
      .setRequired(true);
      
      const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(spielinput);
      const secondActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(grundinput);
      modals.addComponents(firstActionRow, secondActionRow);

      
      
   
  
  const spielersucheerweitertEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle(`Spieler suchen Spieler `)
  .setColor('#00ff0c')
  .setDescription(stripIndents`Drücke auf denn Button um eine Spielersuche Anzufragen!`)
  .setFooter({ text: 'YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY'})
  .setTimestamp();
  
  
  
 
     
  const buttonsa = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('buttonanfrage')
          .setEmoji('')
                    .setLabel('Spielersuche Anfragen')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
            );
      
      
      client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if (interaction.isButton()) {
            const buttonID = interaction.customId
            if (buttonID === 'buttonanfrage') {
              await interaction.showModal(modals);
            }
        }
    });

    client.on('interactionCreate',  (modalSubmit) => {
      if (!modalSubmit.isModalSubmit()) return;
    
  const ginputdata = modalSubmit.fields.getTextInputValue('grundinput');
    const sinputdata = modalSubmit.fields.getTextInputValue('spielinput');
      modalSubmit.reply({
        content:'**Wähle deine Plattform!**', components: [pfmenü], ephemeral: true });
      
      client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if (!interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) return;
       

    
    
  const selected = await interaction.values.join(', ');
      
  const spielersucheerweitertEmbedfertig = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle(`${ginputdata}`)
  .setColor('#00ff0c')
  .setDescription(stripIndents`Spiel: \`${sinputdata}\`
  Plattform:  \`${selected}\``)
  .setFooter({ text: 'YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY'})
  .setTimestamp();

        await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [spielersucheerweitertEmbedfertig] });
        return await interaction.update({ content: '**Spielersuche wurde erfolgreich Angefragt!**', components: [] });
      });

     
    });
    
  
  
    await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [spielersucheerweitertEmbed], components: [buttonsa] });
    return await interaction.reply({ content: 'Spielersuche Embed wurde versendet!', ephemeral: true });

}


};
```

I've looked at the code several times but have no idea why he's doing it more and more often

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if (!interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) return;
       

    
    
  const selected = await interaction.values.join(', ');
      
  const spielersucheerweitertEmbedfertig = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle(`${ginputdata}`)
  .setColor('#00ff0c')
  .setDescription(stripIndents`Spiel: \`${sinputdata}\`
  Plattform:  \`${selected}\``)
  .setFooter({ text: 'YANKEEUNIT91 COMMUNITY'})
  .setTimestamp();
        //executed when the button with the buttonanfrage custom ID is clicked
        await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [spielersucheerweitertEmbedfertig] });
        return await interaction.update({ content: '**Spielersuche wurde erfolgreich Angefragt!**', components: [] });
      });

     
    });
    
  
    //This block is executed when the function is run
    await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [spielersucheerweitertEmbed], components: [buttonsa] });
    return await interaction.reply({ content: 'Spielersuche Embed wurde versendet!', ephemeral: true });

}
```

The issue you are experiencing is caused by the fact that both of these blocks of code are being executed, which is resulting in the same message and update being sent multiple times.

So you have 2 options:

1. Remove the second block of code that sends the message and updates
   the interaction. This will prevent the message and update from being
   sent multiple times.
2. Add a flag to track whether or not the message and update have
   already been sent. You can then check the flag before sending the
   message and update to ensure that they are only sent once.